# Incompatible Integer to pointer conversion sending 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') to parameter of type 'NSInteger *' (aka 'int *')

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I'm trying to parse an integer from a NSDictionary using the code

`[activeItem setData_id:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dict valueForKeyPath:@"data_id"]] integerValue]];`

However, this is giving me this error: `Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') to parameter of type 'NSInteger *' (aka 'int *')`

setData_id takes an integer as a parameter. If I want to parse to a string, `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dict valueForKeyPath:@"data_id"]]` works perfectly.

What I'm doing here is parsing the result of valueForKeyPath to a String, then parsing an integer from that.

Comment: Observe that one data type contains `*` and the other doesn't.

Comment: @JamEngulfer221 Post the definition of `setData_id:`.

Comment: Yep. Observed that. setData_id is synthesised from an NSInteger. More specifically, `@property (readwrite) NSInteger *data_id;`

Comment: Drop the `*`.  You don't want a pointer.

Comment: And that is a screwy way to do the data conversion.  There is no need to invoke `stringWithFormat` -- just apply `integerValue` directly to the result from `valueForKeyPath`.

Comment: (This is basic pointer stuff which you should know pretty well *before* you attempt to do Objective-C programming.)

Comment: @HotLicks I have such dreams about people using Objective-C... : S

Comment: I dropped the * from the definition and it all seems good. Thanks! I'm new to Objective C and came from Java, which has a distinct lack of pointers. And I didn't actually know that pointers were a thing before, so yeah :/

Comment: @HotLicks Ugly pointer syntax from C is the problem here. Many times I have found myself doing `CGFloat*` out of habit.

Comment: Java had pointers too, they just called them "references", and you didn't have a choice as to whether you used them or not.

Comment: (In Java you can't have a pointer (reference) to `int`, but in C you can.  In Java you can't have an instance of an object as a local variable, but in C++ you can.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

How is your `setData_id:` method declared?

Looks like it expect an `NSInteger *` rather than a `NSInteger`...

Either it is declared as:

```
- ( void )setData_id: ( NSInteger )value;
```

And you can use your code.

Otherwise, it means it is declared as:

```
- ( void )setData_id: ( NSInteger * )value;
```

It might be a typo... If you really need an integer pointer, then you may use (assuming you know what you are doing in terms of scope):

```
NSInteger i = [ [ NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", [ dict valueForKeyPath: @"data_id" ] ] integerValue ];
[ activeItem setData_id: &i ];
```

But I think you just made a typo, adding a pointer (`NSInteger *`), while you meant `NSInteger`.

Note: If `setData_id` is a property, the same applies:

```
@property( readwrite, assign ) NSInteger data_id;
```

versus:

```
@property( readwrite, assign ) NSInteger * data_id;
```

I guess you wrote the second example, while meaning the first one...

Comment: No, I want the end result to be an integer. setData_id takes an integer as a parameter. What I'm doing here is parsing the result of valueForKeyPath to a String, then getting the integer value.

Comment: By the way, setData_id is synthesised from a property.

Comment: @JamEngulfer221 You have defined the properly incorrectly.

Answer (score 4):

**The property is defined incorrectly.**

It should be:

```
@property (readwrite) NSInteger data_id;
```

instead of

```
@property (readwrite) NSInteger *data_id;
```

---

You are attempting to pass an integer value to a format that expects to have a pointer type.

Either use

```
[activeItem setData_id:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dict valueForKeyPath:@"data_id"]]];
```

or

```
[activeItem setData_id:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[dict valueForKeyPath:@"data_id"] integerValue]]];
```

---

If you need to set an integer, drop the `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@"]` - this creates a string.

```
[activeItem setData_id:[[dict valueForKeyPath:@"data_id"] integerValue]];
```

Comment: Not an "object type" -- a pointer type.  The problem is the bogus definition of setData_id.

Comment: Sorry, but still wrong.  You haven't fixed the problem.

Comment: @HotLicks Hm? Here, I put it in bold. ;-)

Comment: I can only get it right when question is updated with all relevant information

Answer (score 0):

Use **integerValue** and **intValue** where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 15.3 has started throwing errors with incompatible pointer types. Quick fix is to see if there are any instances where NSInteger variable is declared as

> NSInteger *index;

and replace it with

> NSInteger index

It should work with the above fix.